# How to suspend an object from two points

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm looking to create a physics animation of a guitar slung over a body using its sling.

So there's one body which acts as a parent and collision object.

A sling / two slings (made to look like one if it's easier) attached to the parent body

A guitar suspended from either end by the sling. The guitar should collide with the body.

I've looked at all sorts of tutorials but nothing has come close.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use a [hinge or point constraint](https://i.imgur.com/We8ypbp.gif) for each hinge point.

Comment: @Leander any chance of that Blender file please? That's exactly what I'm after :-) But I don't know how to add multiple constraints to one object...